# Non-exhaustive patterns error

Tags: haskell, int, option-type

My function takes a list of Maybe Int as its argument. If the element = Nothing it should print a . and if the element is a Just Int it'll print the number. 
I thought i had captured a basecase but i don't think i quite got the right one.. I get a non-exhaustive pattern error.

```
replaceValue :: [Maybe Int] -> String
replaceValue (x:xs) 
    | (x:xs) == []        = []
    | isNothing x == True = '.':replaceValue xs
    | isJust x == True    = intToDigit(fromJust x):(replaceValue xs)
```

A nod in the right direction would be highly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `x:xs` only matches a non-empty list. The guard `(x:xs) == []` can *never* succeed.

You probably meant this:

```
replaceValue [] = []
replaceValue (x:xs)
  | isNothing x = ...
  | isJust    x = ...
```

Note also that `... == True` is the same result as just `...`. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

@MathematicalOrchid has already answered.

I want to add that using `isNothing/isJust/fromJust` makes your code more complex than it should be. Further, `fromJust` is dangerous in general, since it crashes if you pass `Nothing` to it -- here you correctly prevent this with the `isJust` guard, but it's easy to forget that in large programs.

The good news is that you can use pattern matching to avoid all these auxiliary functions:

```
replaceValue :: [Maybe Int] -> String
replaceValue []             = []
replaceValue (Nothing : xs) = '.' : replaceValue xs
replaceValue (Just a : xs)  = intToDigit a : replaceValue xs
```

Once you get more familiar with Haskell you will be able to rewrite standard recursion schemes such as the one above in a more compact form, exploiting a few higher order library functions.

```
replaceValue :: [Maybe Int] -> String
replaceValue = map (maybe '.' intToDigit)
```

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid and chi thanks for your answers, helped me alot. :-) Thanks for your tips, they help a beginner alot!

Comment: I actually just ran into another error. I have a data type Sudoku :: [[Maybe Int]], i have a function that reads a textfile, prints to Sudoku (this is working all fine) and should return the type IO Sudoku, but i've no idea how to return that. If i write return (The sudoku i got) i get some error saying expected type IO Sudoku does not match the actualy type Sudoku.

Comment: @Rewbert Open another question and provide a code snippet -- it's hard to guess to what is going on.